# Prove that the sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this sequence:

$x_n = \dfrac{5n^6 + 6}{(n^4 + 1)(n^2 - 2)}$

I can prove that it is bounded below and I can find the limit. But I do not understand how to show that it is monotone. It seems like it is decreasing for $n>1$, but should I *really* show the difference between $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If it converges, then it is bounded.

Comment: Is it important to show that the sequence is monotone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the proposed sequence converges, then it is bounded.

Having said that, let us take the limit:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^{6} + 6}{(n^{4} + 1)(n^{2} - 2)}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5 + 6/n^{6}}{(1 + 1/n^{4})(1 - 2/n^{2})}\\\\
& = \frac{5 + 0}{(1 + 0)(1 - 0)} = 5
\end{align*}

Since it is convergent, then it is bounded.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know this rule, but I think you mistyped the limit(5/2 should be 5/1).

Comment: You are welcome! And thanks for pointing out the typo.